# Soulpos package definitions

Tags: tikz-pgf, soul

Here is the soulpos package link:: https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/soulpos

I wrote the code from soulpos  manual, But I don't know how can I use \ulpgfB \ulpgfC definitions?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soulpos}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\ulposdef{\ulpgfB}{\raisebox{-.75ex}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}\clip (0,-1pt) rectangle (\ulwidth,1pt);
\draw[color=black!40,line width=.7pt,decorate,
decoration={snake,amplitude=.3pt,segment length=1mm,}](0,0) -- +(\ulwidth+3pt,0);\end{tikzpicture}}}

\ulposdef\ulpgfC[xoffset=.15em]{%
 \ifulstarttype{0}{\def\arr{|}}{\def\arr{<}}\ifulendtype{0}{\edef\arr{\arr-|}}{\edef\arr{\arr->}}%
\raisebox{-.7ex}{\tikz\draw[\arr,color=black!40,line width=1pt](0,0) -- +(\ulwidth-1pt,0);}}

\begin{document}
 thanks \ulpgfB{thanks} thanks
thanks \ulpgfC{hrhhgrh} thanks

\end{document}
```

Comment: looks ok. Did you compile twice?

Comment: I didn't understand you fine, you can run one,  not twice, *Do you mean compile them in one definition?(answer:no)

Comment: What is your problem with the example? It works fine, you only need to do two compilations.

Comment: some of errors: `Undefined control sequence. thanks \ulpgfC{hrhhgrh}` + `You can't use end-group character }' after \the. \end{document}`

Comment: show the complete log-file of the example.

Comment: I was using LuaLatex, it solved with Xelatex. but that not mentioned in package manual!!!

Comment: Oh, well next time mention this. It will work with lualatex if you load \usepackage{luatex85}, but I will notify the author, he should correct this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer on mine question:
The soulpos package work with XeLatex converter not with LuaLatex.

So The resulting photo:

[image]